# JS convert simple 24 hour string to 12 hours

Tags: javascript

I'm using Vue.
How can I convert my 24-hour time to 12-hour time when it's a string, not a date object?

For example, I need to convert "17:30" to 5:30pm.

I'm adding multiple variations of start and end times for different formatting needs: text messages, vuetify calendar, etc.

```js
const timeAmPm=s=>s.split(':').reduce((a,c)=>a?(s===a+c)?a+c+'am':a+c+'pm':c%12+':','')


console.log(timeAmPm('17:30'))  // 5:30pm
console.log(timeAmPm('10:30'))  // 10:30am
```

Comment: See `String.split` and `parseInt`

Comment: Have you tried something ? You should probably start by extracting the hour value and converting it to an integer.

Comment: There are a *bunch* of duplicates to this question.  Can you show us what you tried, and describe where specifically you are stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it, it works for both - String or Date instance.

```js
function formatAMPM(date) {
  if (typeof date === "string") {
    let [hours, minutes] = date.split(":");
    let ampm = "AM";

    if (Number(hours) > 12) {
      hours = Number(hours) - 12;
      ampm = "PM";
    }

    return `${hours}:${minutes} ${ampm}`;

  } else if (date instanceof Date) {
    let hours = date.getHours();
    let minutes = date.getMinutes();

    let ampm = hours >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM";

    hours = hours % 12;
    hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;

    let strTime = hours + ":" + minutes + " " + ampm;

    return strTime;
  }

  return date;
}

console.log(formatAMPM(new Date()))
console.log(formatAMPM('20:20'))
```